# Trying out GUN.js, getting a error I don't understand

Tags: node.js, database, p2p, gun, gundb

I am trying to get started with Gun db, I want to build a completely decentralized database for one of my projects, I have local instances of an nodejs api running on the users machines, now I want to use Gun.js to add decentralized databasing to each instance.

I have this code on "Client 1"

```
import GUN from 'gun';
const gun = new GUN();
gun.get('bb10a2e7-aa34-4d87-8160-1b1c7356c13a').get('popularMoveis').put('movie 1');
```

and this on "Client 2"

```
import GUN from 'gun';
const gun = new GUN();
const popularMovies = gun.get('bb10a2e7-aa34-4d87-8160-1b1c7356c13a').get('popularMoveis');
console.log(popularMovies);
```

But I get this error
"Error: addMembership EHOSTUNREACH
at Socket.addMembership (node:dgram:852:11)
at Socket. (C:\Users\Talon - Personal\Desktop\Cinnatorr\DatabaseTesting\node_modules\gun\lib\multicast.js:28:18)
at Socket.emit (node:events:525:35)
at startListening (node:dgram:181:10)
at node:dgram:369:7
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
errno: -4073,
code: 'EHOSTUNREACH',
syscall: 'addMembership'
}"

**please advice on what possible issues could be, I am still not 100% sure if a server is a requirement or not, does gun.js work exactly the exactly same in the browser and in nodejs?**